# how to customize google map with image for my website

Tags: html, google-maps

[enter link description here](http://dev5.wethedevelopers.com/test/dhaval/googlemap.html)

I want to change this image to my image how can i change this. anyone have any idea please help me how to use image so that it can be zoom and where can i put my image so that it works perfectly

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the source code for that site.

Comment: i have seen my source code and there it show something link actually i am beginner so i cant understand what is it exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking is Google Map's [**Image map types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=pl#ImageMapTypes), here is an [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image?hl=pl)

**From your comments**:

I don't get where the difficultly lies to see the image.

```
var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
          '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 1738000,
  name: 'Moon'
};
```

See the **`return`** statement.

Comment: Yes i have seen that example but i cant find where can i put my image so that it will show in my map

Comment: you didnt get my question i am saying that i want to put my image into map but where can i put ?

Comment: i want to put my photo replace with that lady how can i my question is just it is... :)

Comment: how many tiles i have to create or what i have to create so that i can put my customize path